# I want my program to store multiple records but it is storing only one temporary record

Tags: c#

I am making a project which involves dealing with some hospital records system. My task is to record multiple information of that patient, but my program is storing only one record.
How should I modify it that it should store multiple records of patient.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h79ro.png)

Comment: Paste code from image in your answer please

Comment: @Roma I think he is asking a question :p

Comment: Multiple records means you have to *iterate* something (using `for`, `while`, `foreach`, *recursion*, etc.). You can ask user how many patients he want to enter first. Or make entering infinite until a special condition met (e.g. empty value or you can organize higher level menu: 1) add patient 2) view patients 3) exit program).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the next question "Next patient?" and store the answer in some variable. In the most outer scope you can add a *while* loop.

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter("Data.txt"))
{
    var isNextPatient = true;
    while(isNextPatient)
    {
        // Here writing the record of one patient.

        Console.WriteLine("Next patient?");
        // E.g. 'true' or 'false'
        isNextPatient = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    };
}
```